# Quedarse con una palabra en concreto de una frase y guardarla en una variable - Javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo un problema. Supongamos que yo tengo una lista `var Questions = ["Un examen","las soluciones mejores"]`. Usando Javascript, pulsando un botón, que escoja la palabra examen, retirando Un, y alojando el valor *examen* en una variable aparte. La lista Questions sirve para ir alojando datos a medida que el usuario va proporcionandolos desde un `<input>`. En el caso de que pusiera la palabra *exámenes*, tendría que detectar dicha palabra, y lo mismo como si pone la palabra *examen*. He estado buscando, y lo que he encontrado es la función `search()` pero solo me devuelve un número. ¿Hay alguna posibilidad de hacerlo con Javascript? Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo único que necesitas es saber si la palabra fue encontrada en `Questions`, recorre las preguntas y verifica si contiene la palabra usando `.indexOf()`

```js
let buscar = ['examen', 'exámenes'];
let Questions = ["Un examen","las soluciones mejores"];

function buscaExamen() {
    let result = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < Questions.length; i++) {
        for(let j = 0; j < buscar.length; j ++) {
            if(Questions[i].indexOf(buscar[j]) != -1) {
                result.push(buscar[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(buscaExamen());
// Agregar elemento
Questions.push('Tres exámenes');
console.log(buscaExamen());
```

Comment: Gracias, Triby, al final he conseguido algo similar!

Answer (score 0):

Podrias usar em metodo substring, el cual se maneja por indices. 
  Ejemplo
  cualquierCadena = "Mozilla";

// Muestra "Moz"
    print(cualquierCadena.substring(0,3));
    print(cualquierCadena.substring(3,0));